# Combine two rows in csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I need to combine two rows removing the space between them. What I need is:

My csv with single column:

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|
      "imperfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
```

My output needs to be :

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
```

But what I got is:

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line","2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line","2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
```

My code is:

```
fIn = open("01new.csv", "r")
fOut = open("output.csv", "w")

fOut.write(",".join([line for line in fIn]).replace("\n",""))

fIn.close()
fOut.close()
```

How can I get the output I need?

---

When I run [the code from Pranav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67639860/843953), I get this output:

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"

"2021-05-13"|"test"|"imperfect line"

"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
```

And in addition i had empty delimiter that too get vanished For eg:

My Actual File is

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"perfect line"

"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|
"imperfect line"

"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"perfect line"
```

I need Like :

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"perfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"imperfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"perfect line"
```

Comment: That i used to merge the row that moves to next line

Comment: Hmm, a new line after a separator is weird. But csv files can contain new lines inside quoted fields and the csv module handles that smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you joined *every* line with a comma, and then removed the line separators so that everything is in a single line.

Instead, I suggest you should use the `csv` module to correctly read CSV files. If the row you're currently processing and the row you previously processed both have a total of three items, join the two rows.

```
import csv

num_columns = 3

# Read all lines from input file
with open("input_file") as f:
    in_csv = [line for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")]
```

This gives us the following list:

```
[['2021-05-13', 'test', 'perfect line'],
 ['2021-05-13', 'test', ''],
 ['      "imperfect line"'],
 ['2021-05-13', 'test', 'perfect line']]
```

Notice that the first imperfect line still has three elements, but one of them is blank. Additionally, the remainder of that imperfect line is untrimmed and on the next line.
Finally, I also see that when there's a single item on the line, the csv reader doesn't get rid of the quotes.
Let's change our code to fix these problems:

```
in_csv = []
with open("input_file") as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"):
        modified_line = [item.strip() for item in line if item.strip()]
        if len(modified_line) == 1: modified_line[0] = modified_line[0].replace('"', '')
        in_csv.append(modified_line)
```

Or if you want a list-comprehension:

```
with open("input_file") as f:
    in_csv = [[item.strip() for item in line if item.strip()] for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")]
    in_csv = [row if len(row) > 1 else [row[0].replace('"', '')] for row in in_csv]
```

Which gives us the cleaned-up list:

```
[['2021-05-13', 'test', 'perfect line'],
 ['2021-05-13', 'test'],
 ['imperfect line'],
 ['2021-05-13', 'test', 'perfect line']]
```

Now, we can apply our logic to fix the imperfect lines.

```
# Empty list for output lines
out_csv = []

# Iterate over rows:
previousrow = None
for currentrow in in_csv:
    if previousrow is not None and len(previousrow) + len(currentrow) == num_columns:
        previousrow.extend(currentrow) # Add all elements from current row to previous
        previousrow = None
    else:  # 
        out_csv.append(currentrow) # Add current row to output
        previousrow = currentrow
```

This gives us the correct `out_csv`:

```
[['2021-05-13', 'test', 'perfect line'],
 ['2021-05-13', 'test', 'imperfect line'],
 ['2021-05-13', 'test', 'perfect line']]
```

Finally, write the output file:

```
with open("output_file", "w") as f:
    csv.writer(f, delimiter="|", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL).writerows(out_csv)
```

Which gives the output:

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"imperfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
```

---

To address your comments and the edit to your question:

1. You have legitimate *empty elements* in your rows, so we're going to have to change our logic
2. You have empty rows in your input file already! You can just skip them as you read the input file.

Incorporating the changes needed for 1. and 2.:

```
in_csv = []
with open("input_file") as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"):
        # If line is empty, move on to the next
        if not line:
            continue

        # Code only comes here if the line isn't empty
        # DO the rest of the processing here
        # Strip whitespaces from all elements of the row
        stripped_line = [item.strip() for item in line]

        # If the last element of the stripped line is empty, delete that element from this line
        if stripped_line[-1] == "":
            del stripped_line[-1]

        # If line contains only one item, replace all quotes in that item
        if len(stripped_line) == 1: 
            stripped_line[0] = stripped_line[0].replace('"', '')

        in_csv.append(stripped_line)
```

Writing this as a list-comprehension is left as an exercise for the reader :)

3. You have *four* columns, so change that: `num_columns = 4`.

After I make these changes and run the code, I get the following output:

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"perfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"imperfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"perfect line"
```

Comment: New empty line is added after each row in the output, how to remove it

Comment: That's weird. What do you get from `print(out_csv)`? @avmantra

Comment: I need to edit in your answer but its in queue

Comment: @avmantra You aren't supposed to edit answers to reply to them. Add it in a comment or a pastebin or edit your question.

Comment: Question Edited

Comment: Jeez, don't replace your entire question with _my answer!_ Just add the part you want to tell me to your old question. Sit tight. I'm going to rollback and edit it for you

Comment: @avmantra I made the edit to your question already. Hold on, I'm changing my answer

Comment: Ok i am Waiting

Comment: @avmantra Take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: Even the New Empty Appears How to rectify that

Comment: @avmantra You mean the empty line appears even when you run the updated code?

Comment: Yes It appears again

Comment: @avmantra I can't reproduce that. Check your code to make sure you've included all the latest changes, and that your input is actually in the format you described in your edit.

Comment: Requested you in Linkedin as i cannot continue to chat box due to low reputation , please  accept so that i can send the code there

Comment: @avmantra Can you ask on the [python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)? I don't currently have access to LinkedIn

Comment: That too need 20 reputation so i can't is there any other way...!

Comment: @avmantra here: https://replit.com/join/rvxvkcsw-pranavhosangadi

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `'\n'` with `'|\n'` and `strip()` to remove leading and trailing spaces

```
fIn = open("01new.csv", "r")
fOut = open("output.csv", "w")

fOut.write("\n".join([line.strip() for line in fIn]).replace("|\n","|"))

fIn.close()
fOut.close()
```

Comment: It Prints 2 and 3 line in the 2 row itself

Answer (score 0):

@Pranav's answer is really great. Here is a "simple" one, without the CSV library:

```py
with open("01new.csv", "r") as fIn, open("output.csv", "w") as fOut:
    for r in fIn.readlines():
        if '|' == r[-2]::
            fOut.write(r.strip())
        else:
            fOut.write(r.strip()+",\n")
```

Basically it checks whether the second to last character is your separator (because the last is the `\n` newline). If yes, it prints it to the new file, without a new line. If not, it's either the second part of the imperfect line, or a correct line. Add it to the file with a comma and a new line.

Comment: It also prints in the same line

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/se0wbY/2) to reconstruct the line in the proper format:

```
import re 

with open(your_file, 'r') as f:
    s=re.sub(r'^([^|]*\|)([^|]*\|)\n\s*([^|\n]*\n)',r'\1\2\3', f.read(), flags=re.M)
    print(s)
```

Prints:

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"imperfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|"perfect line"
```

To use a string with csv, feed the string to the  [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) library:

```
import csv 
import re 
from io import StringIO

with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    s=re.sub(r'^([^|]*\|)([^|]*\|)\n\s*([^|\n]*\n)',r'\1\2\3', f.read(), flags=re.M)    
    for row in csv.reader(StringIO(s), delimiter='|'):
        print(row)
```

Prints:

```
['2021-05-13', 'test', 'perfect line']
['2021-05-13', 'test', 'imperfect line']
['2021-05-13', 'test', 'perfect line']
```

---

---

Another way is to recognize that with a `\n` inserted unquoted into the CSV file, you have a broken csv file.

You can reconstruct the record structure by reading the csv one field at a time then reconstituting into the 3 fields per record (4 fields if you insert the blank field) like so:

```
import csv 

def next_field(f):
    for line in f:
        for field in line.strip().split('|'):
            if field: yield field.strip('"')
        
with open(fn, 'r') as f, open(fn_out, 'w') as fo:
    w=csv.writer(fo,delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for r in (t[:2]+('',)+t[2:] for t in zip(*[iter(next_field(f))]*3)):
        w.writerow(r)
```

Your `fn_out` file is now:

```
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"perfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"imperfect line"
"2021-05-13"|"test"|""|"perfect line"
```